# What schema if I have many measures

Tags: database-design, olap

Forgive me if I misuse any words. I'm a c++ programmer with some basic DB knowledge.

I'm developing an analytics engine for simulation data for vehicle engines. OLAP seems like a good fit but I haven't done an exhaustive search for different methodologies.

What I'm stuck on is how to structure my tables/cubes. Most examples I've seen have 1 or 2 measures and my simulations can generate 100s or even 1,000s of different measures for each test. The measures have some hierarchy to them, usually encoded in the name of the measure. For example, there may be TEMP.sensor1, TEMP.sensor2, TEMP.sensor3, TORQUE.sensor1, TORQUE.sensor2, etc. This dimension is used to slice.

Another dimension is different tests being run. There may be several different highway tests which act as different inputs to the simulation. The tests are either analyzed independently or aggregated into a single set of measures.

Does each test belong in a row of a fact table that has 1 measure for each of my statistics? Are there other approaches? Is this even a suitable problem for a database and OLAP?